# LINQ entity join with while using trim function to parameter

Tags: c#, linq, join, trim

I have t.arg which contains `"abc|efg|xyz"`
and b.arg which is `"xyz"`
I want to compare them while making join:

```
join t in db.Tdb on b.arg.Substring(b.arg.LastIndexOf('|') + 1)  equals t.arg
```

I'm getting the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 LastIndexOf(Char)' 
>       method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

**both arguments are strings**

What can be done to solve this ?

Comment: I want to get all chars after last "|" to the right from b.arg and use this to > equals t.arg.

Comment: So, yes you want to check `EndsWith`.

Comment: John b.arg.EndsWith("|" + t.arg) not working. I get error that b.arg is not in scope on the left side of equals

Comment: I think the issue is before the code posted.  You have an array of characters instead of a string.  You need to find out why you do not have a string.

Comment: I think we will need to get some more context here. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: problem is that t.arg can be "abc|def|hyz" and I want to get only xyz. so I dont understand how b.arg.EndsWith("|" + t.arg) will help that.
and in b.arg there is only xyz. That's why I want to modify t.arg to get xyz and compare it to b.arg

Comment: I just read your edit from yesterday. Have you mixed up t and b? In your current code, if it worked, `b.arg` contains `xyz`, so `b.arg.Substring(b.arg.LastIndexOf('|') + 1)` would return `xyz` and then compare it to `t.arg` which contains `abc|efg|xyz`, so the evaluation would return false. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is no built-in Linq -> T-SQL translation for the LastIndexOf method. AFAIK, there is no directly corresponding function in SQL server either. You will have to:

1. Write a scalar-valued user defined function in your database that performs the equivalent operation to LastIndexOf
2. Add a wrapper method decorated with the EdmFunction attribute to your C# code that handles the translation to the T-SQL function, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you're trying to write the equivalent of the SQL `bArg = tArg OR bArg LIKE '%|' + tArg`. I believe `.EndsWith` should achieve this for you. Unfortunately it isn't possible to use it in the `join` part, but you can use it in the `where` part.

```
var result = 
    from b in collection1
    from t in collection2
    where b.arg == t.arg || b.arg.EndsWith("|" + t.arg)
    select new { B = b, T = t };
```

The `where` clause here should be roughly equivalent to your SQL query.

Since you didn't see how `a == b || EndsWith` is relevant, consider these examples as to why it works:

- `abc|def|ghi` joining `ghi`
- `ghi` joining `ghi`

If we use your method, we get the following results from your `Substring`:

- `abc|def|ghi` becomes `ghi`
- `ghi`, because it doesn't contain `|` gets an index of -1, which with the + 1 makes it 0, thus it simply becomes `ghi`

Now, what happens if we use `==` and `EndsWith`?

- `"abc|def|ghi"` doesn't `== "ghi"`, but it does end with `"|ghi"`, so it satisfies the condition.
- `"ghi"` does `== "ghi"`, so it satisfies the condition.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/KSOK9312)

Comment: I get error : the name b.arg is not in scope on the left side of equals. Consider swapping the expression on the other side of equals

Comment: @David corrected now. I forgot you couldn't do that in `join` and I didn't have time to fix my answer earlier.